# Hide console for Tkinter app on OSX

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to hide the Terminal when I launch a GUI Tkinter based app, but when I double click the app.py file on OSX, the Terminal window appears.  I've tried changing the extension to .pyw and tried launching it with /usr/bin/pythonw, but no matter what, the Terminal window still appears.

I've even tried adding the try/except below, but when I run it I get the error: 'invalid command name "console"' in the Terminal window that appears.

```
from Tkinter import *

class MainWindow(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        try:
            self.tk.call('console', 'hide')
        except TclError, err:
           print err

win = MainWindow()
win.mainloop()
```

I haven't been able to find any way to hide the Terminal window from appearing.  Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By double-clicking a `.py` file on OS X, you are likely launching a Python gui instance via the `Python Launcher.app` supplied with OS X Pythons.  You can verify that by selecting the `.py` file in the Finder and doing a `Get Info` on it.  Python Launcher is a very simple-minded app that starts Python via a Terminal.app command.  To directly launch your own Python GUI app, the preferred approach is to create a simple app using [py2app](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2app/).  There's a brief tutorial [here](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html#tutorial).

EDIT:

There are other ways, of course, but most likely any of them would be adding more levels of indirection.  To make a normal launchable, "double-clickable" application, you need some sort of app structure. That's what `py2app` lets you create directly.

A very simple-minded alternative is to take advantage of the AppleScript Editor's ability to create a launcher app.  In the `AppleScript` editor:

- `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript
  Editor.app` in OS X 10.6
- `/Applications/AppleScript/Script
  Editor.app` in 10.5

make a new script similar to this:

```
do shell script "/path/to/python /path/to/script.py &> /dev/null &"
```

and then `Save As..` with `File Format -> Application`.  Then you'll have a double-clickable app that will launch another app.  You can create something similar with Apple's `Automater.app`.  But, under the covers, they are doing something similar to what `py2app` does for you, just with more layers on top.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  So is it safe to say that there is no way of simply suppressing the Terminal from launching without using py2app?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer by Ned Deily, im my case when I tried to launch the Python application using an AppleScript application, it did not work initially. I discovered that it has something to to with some kind of encoding error (I am using UTF-8 and in the past I had felt need to configure it to UTF-8).

So, after further investigation, I discovered that I can accomplish this by creating an AppleScript application with the following code (adjusting the paths of python3 and of the Python application as needed):

`do shell script "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; /usr/local/bin/python3 '/Users/USER/FOLDER/SCRIPT.py' &> /dev/null &"`

It launches the Python application without any Terminal windows. The AppleScript application can then be personalised with a custom icon as usual, and can be placed in the Dock. When clicked, it will launch the Python intepreter, that still shows up in Dock, but with no visible windows.

I think this may be useful to other users.

Answer (score 0):

'console hide' doesn't hide the Terminal in OS X. It hides Tk's built-in console, which is really a relic from the MacOS Classic days (and which is still commonly used on Windows).