# Saving f.write file to same directory as the askopenfilename was found

Tags: python, file, path, save

I am running this script in Python to find a certain line in a file. `askopenfilename` will ask what file I want to search and the f.write will save the results into a file. How do I automatically save this file in the same place I found the original file?

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

filename = askopenfilename()

file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    if "INF: Camera timeout" in line:
        with open("../timeouts.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(line)
            f.close
```

Also `askopenfilename` opens behind the other windows, how do I make it open on top?

Comment: You left the parentheses off of `f.close`, which makes that a no-op.  You can leave it out entirely because the context manager closes it for you (`with open ...`).  It might make most sense to move the file open outside of the loop so you are not repeatedly opening and closing the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the directory from a path use [`os.path.dirname(path)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname).

I would rewrite your code as:

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

infilename= askopenfilename()
outfilename = join(dirname(infilename), 'timeouts.txt')
with open(infilename, 'r') as f_in, open(outfilename, 'a') as f_out: 
    fout.writelines(line for line in f_in if "INF: Camera timeout" in line)
```

For your second question see [How to give Tkinter file dialog focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375227/how-to-give-tkinter-file-dialog-focus).

*Note:*  Above example partially based on Alex Thornton's [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017123/1322401).