# How to run a Python 3 tkinter app without opening any Terminal windows in Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, tkinter

I developed a GUI app in Python 3. I want to be able to launch it by clicking on the script itself or in a custom-made launching script. I have changed permissions and it's now opening with "Python Launcher" on double-click. But everytime I run my app, I get a lot of windows:

- My Python application (that's the only one I need to be on screen)
- The Python launcher preferences (I could live with this one, but
  would prefer it to be hidden)
- A Terminal window with the default shell (don't need this one)
- Another Terminal window showing the output of the app (like `print`, errors... I don't want this window)

What is the easiest way to get only the GUI on screen, without any Terminal windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion bu linusg, I discovered that I can accomplish this by creating an AppleScript application with the following code (adjusting the paths of python3 and of the Python application as needed):

```
do shell script "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; /usr/local/bin/python3 '/Users/USER/FOLDER/SCRIPT.py' &> /dev/null &"
```

It launches the Python application without Terminal Windows. The AppleScript application can then be personalised with a custom icon as usual, and can be placed in the Dock. When clicked, it will launch the Python intepreter, that still shows up in Dock, but with no visible windows.

I think this may be useful to other users.

Comment: You can set `LSUIElement` (Application is agent) in the `info.plist` file of the packed `.app` application and even the python interpreter won't appear. See here for the detail: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256

Comment: It does not work with my AppleScript application. Maybe that suggestion only applies to a full packed application with its own Python interpreter...?

Comment: After an hour of looking for a way to do this, your solution was he only one that worked as suggested and it's the simplest, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By changing the file extension to `.pyw` (Python Windowed), any terminal/shell/cmd would be hidden by default (I even don't know about the preferences window).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this does not apply to Python 3 on Mac. In fact, I have tried that and it just does the same I have described before.

Comment: Hmm, on windows it works. I've found something else: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1810580/5952681

Comment: I have tryed that, but then I get this error: `error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/Users/USER/FOLDER/SCRIPT.py\", line 1443, in <module>
    print(\" - A preparar interface gr\\xe1fica.\")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\\xe1' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)" number 1`

Comment: It seems that I need to enforce the hidden terminal to accept UTF-8 encoding, but I have no idea how.

Comment: What have you tried? The answer contains two possibilities. Are the terminals hidden??

Comment: But Python 3 does not have those Unicode issues. BTW, it should be `print(" - A preparar interface gr\xe1fica.")`, not `print(\" - A preparar interface gr\\xe1fica.\")`.

Comment: I tried the answer by Ned Deiley (writing an AppleScript launcher). The error message I pasted in my previous comment was taken from the "Results" log in Apple's Script Editor. The app did not launch, so I deleted the last part (&> /dev/null &), just to see the log, and that was the text shown. The Python 3 code runs fine if I launch it from a terminal window, or in IDLE. I think I had a similar issue some time ago, and I had to change Terminal settings to UTF-8. But here I am not seeing how can I change that.

Comment: OK, I discovered that if I add `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; ` in the begining of my AppleScript launcher, it works ok. Litke this: `do shell script "export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; export LANG=en_US.UTF-8; /usr/local/bin/python3 '/Users/USER/FOLDER/SCRIPT.py' &> /dev/null &"`